# React native Expected String but got object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to import the Login module in my index.android.js but it doesnt seem to work? What is wrong in render method?

login.js is located in /screens/login.js

react-native version "0.39.2"

**index.android.js**

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

//login module
var LoginScreen = require('./screens/login');

var app = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <LoginScreen />
    );
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

**login.js** under /screens directory

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
var Button = require('react-native-button');

import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native';


var Login = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    _loginClick: function(event){
        console.log('login tapped');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.inputs}>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
                            placeholder="Username"
                            placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                            value={this.state.username}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            password={true}
                            style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
                            placeholder="Pasword"
                            placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
                            value={this.state.password}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.forgotContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.greyFont}>Forgot Password</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.signin}>
                    <Text style={styles.whiteFont}>Sign In</Text>
                    <Button
                        style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'blue'}}
                        onPress={this._loginClick}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.signup}>
                    <Text style={styles.greyFont}>Don't have an account?<Text style={styles.whiteFont}>  Sign Up</Text></Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    },

});

module.exports = Login;
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception in logcat?

Comment: Does it say in which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `react-native-button` is referring to [this](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button), then you are importing the component incorrectly. It should be:

```
import Button from 'react-native-button';
```

This is because Button.js is exporting the component using `export default class` instead of `module.export`. So, you should use `import` instead of `require()`. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) regarding `export`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your Button component, remove it. Secondly you are missing styles too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```js
var Button = require('react-native-button');
```

for this

```js
import Button from 'react-native-button';
```